# Why same strings are not equal in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

The string generated by the JSON package is not equal to the same looking string, why?

The last equality check in code below is false, why? [playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2Koz)

```
import strformat, json

type Price = tuple[price: float, currency: string]

func `%`*(v: Price): JsonNode = %(fmt"{v.price} {v.currency}")

let v: Price = (214.05, "USD")
let s: string = (%(v)).pretty

echo s                  # => "214.05 USD"
echo s == "214.05 USD"  # => false, why?
```

Comment: `"\"214.05 USD\""`

Comment: Yes, json version contains quotes - you can see that by using `toSeq()` on two strings to see each individual character.

Comment: It's already seen from the `echo s`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [echo proc](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#echo%2Cvarargs%5Btyped%2C%5D) can sometimes be deceptive in terms of representing strings, so I prefer to throw in the [repr proc](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#repr%2CT) which makes sure to represent strings (and other objects) in a more clear way. See the output I get when I add the following lines to the example, representing both sides of the comparison:

```
echo repr(s)
echo repr("214.05 USD")
==>
0x105f5c0b8"\"214.05 USD\""
0x105f1cf70"214.05 USD"
```

Through this representation we can see the strings are really not equal. Your `%` proc formats the contents of the `Price` tuple as a space separated string node, and the [JSON pretty proc](https://nim-lang.org/docs/json.html#pretty%2CJsonNode%2Cint) converts that string node to its JSON representation, which includes double quotes. Thus, to make the last comparison equal we need to write it like this:

```
echo s == "\"214.05 USD\""
```

Another possibility would be to write the comparison accessing the `JsonNode.str` variant field, which avoids involving the mischievous `pretty`:

```
echo (%(v)).str == "214.05 USD"
```